# Using gradle to build Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-testing, android-build

I have an Android project with an "old style" Eclipse project structure. Now I wish to make my application more testable and also use CI to build and test it, however this requires the project to contain gradle build files. Obviously they're absent as I am using Eclipse and I don't have the time to convert the project to Android Studio(will be done later).

My project structure

```
- Name of project
-- AndroidManifest.xml
-- project.properties
-- proguard-project.txt

-- assets
-- libs (containing jar dependencies) 
-- res

-- src
---- com/example/projectname

-- test
---- com/example/projectname/test
```

Besides this I have two other projects in the buildpath which is needed to run my application.

So my questions are:
1) Is it possible to add Gradle build files to an Android Eclipse project? If possible how to do it?
2) How should I do with the other projects I got in my build path? One of the project I know there are gradle dependency for but the other is missing that.

Answer (score 0):

***Is it possible to add Gradle build files to an Android Eclipse project? If possible how to do it?***

Yes it's possible. Just install [Gradle Integration for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44) and then use it according to [documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)

***How should I do with the other projects I got in my build path?***

Considering that you'll migrate in the future on Android Studio it makes sense to:

1. Port all you "old eclipse" project to Gradle
2. [Import](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) them to Android Studio as "Non-Android Studio project."

In most of the cases this procedure will work.